# Odd usage of "penchant"

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Penchant is synonymous with words such as "inclination" and "leaning."

Does the sentence below correctly use the word "penchant"?

> Joe has a *penchant* against the UCLA Bruins.

Answer (score 3):

A [penchant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penchant) is a predisposition in favor of, a predilection for something. I found [this](http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/articles/234242/penchant-against-privacy) on the Net, though. I'd say that he's misusing the word and that the writer or speaker should have said "prejudice" or "bias" against the UCLA Bruins.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/penchant) for questions like this. In addition to providing definitions from more than one dictionary on the left, the Wordnik page shows example usages on the right.

Initially, I didn't like the sentence about Joe and the Bruins. I think of *a penchant for doing something* being used more like *a tendency to do something*.  So, I'd be more inclined to say:

> Joe has a penchant for disliking the Bruins.

When I checked the Wordnik page, I noticed that almost all the usages read *penchant for*, even after I clicked the `Show 10 more examples…` link three or four times. For example:

> ...his penchant for exerting political pressure.
>
> ...a preternaturally eclectic, intellectually minded prog rocker with a penchant for cosmic horror.
>
> ...has a penchant for the use of physical threats and violent analogies in discussions and debates.

Still, 30 or 40 usages on Wordnik hardly constitutes a definitive answer. So, I looked up "has a penchant **against**" on [Google books](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=images&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22has+a+penchant+against%22), I found all of **one hit**, from a 1930 yearbook:

> ...unless perchance some famed alumnus has a penchant against metropolitan papers and for love of Alma Mater keeps his great secret to himself.

When I [changed the search](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=images&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22has+a+penchant+for%22) to "has a penchant **for**", however, there were **137,000**. Interestingly enough, the [very first result](http://books.google.com/books?id=9re1vfFh04sC&pg=PA288&dq=%22has%20a%20penchant%20for%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BMCkUPSsGsjRyAHZo4Bg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22has%20a%20penchant%20for%22&f=false) was from a dictionary of idioms, which says that  the idiom "Have a penchant for" means:

> Have a tendency or taste for. For example, *He has a penchant for saying the wrong thing*, or *She has a strong penchant for baroque music*.

I also tried these searches on Google books:

- "a penchant against" ([36](http://books.google.com/books?id=9re1vfFh04sC&pg=PA288&dq=%22has%20a%20penchant%20for%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BMCkUPSsGsjRyAHZo4Bg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22has%20a%20penchant%20for%22&f=false) results returned)
- "a penchant of" ([two thousand](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22a+penchant+of%22&oq=%22a+penchant+of%22&gs_l=serp.3...150798.150858.2.151769.2.2.0.0.0.1.131.217.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.heYmKlIvT5g&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1f5346e9297c1c7a&bpcl=38625945&biw=1256&bih=825) results returned)
- "a penchant for" ([4.7 million](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22a+penchant+for%22&oq=%22a+penchant+for%22&gs_l=serp.3...16369.16584.1.16902.3.3.0.0.0.0.98.268.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.wj_4IKQqZ_4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1f5346e9297c1c7a&bpcl=38625945&biw=1256&bih=825) results returned)

You can say whatever you want to say, and write whatever you'd like to write, but, as for me, I'd have a penchant for avoiding the usage found in your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

*penchant* has these definitions:

> noun: a strong and continued inclination ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penchant))
>
> noun: A definite liking; a strong inclination ([freedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/penchant))
>
> noun: a liking for, an enjoyment of, or a habit of doing something,
>   especially something that other people might not like ([cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/penchant))
>
> noun: a strong inclination or liking; bent or taste
>   ([wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/penchant))

[image: google search result]

*(first thing that pops up in google when 'inclination definition' is all that is typed)*

Going by the definitions, and substituting *penchant* with *(**an**) [inclination](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inclination)*, I don't believe that *penchant* is being misused. Does it seem a bit off? Yeah, but that doesn't make it wrong.

Also, if you see the synonyms for `inclination`, you'd see that it corresponds with Bill Franke's want for *bias* and also corresponds to J.R.'s *dislike*.

<sup>(Regarding my statement about J.R.'s *dislike*, the sentence could also be worded:</sup>

> Joe has *a liking against* the UCLA Bruins.

<sup>*I linked *inclination* to help support why I say that *penchant* is not being misused.)</sup>